# What Android phone has the best camera?

Tags: android, cameraphones

I am going to buy an Android mobile phone and I want to be sure it has good camera (and video camera).

What phones do you recommend that have good camera?

Comment: This question is going to be difficult to answer in the stack exchange format. Every answer is equally valid, thus, it is not the best question. I would suggest writing your question to ask about a specific phone rather then keep it opened ended as it is - or it may get closed.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate (but not cross-post) of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/whats-the-best-android-device-for-photography

Comment: It doesn't look like you got the best answer on that site matt. That is a tough one to answer.

Comment: Yeah, the basic answer is that Nokia was the only company that cared about making awesome cameras in their phones, followed (but with a different philosophy) by Apple. Especially now with the Nokia/Microsoft sellout, that leaves Android pretty much at the bottom of the barrel. The best thing you can hope for is some marketers excited about upping the megapixel count and _oooh_ dual LED flashes. The iPhone 4S camera is supposed to improve on Apple's already strong position in this regard; maybe some Android maker will rise to the challenge — but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: @mattdm I think you're forgetting about Sony Ericsson, I bought K750i to (successfully) replace my dead 2.0MP P&S because it was the first phone with AF camera (and two-stage release button). I suspect LED flash was a new thing also.

Comment: very puzzled by your comments @mattdm - The camera in the HTC Desire HD is significantly better than the Apple 4 - greater pixel count, copes with a wider range of light conditions. Better colour balance than some of the Fuji handhelds.

Comment: @Rory: look at [HTC's own page](http://www.htc.com/www/smartphones/htc-desire-hd/#specs) to see what I mean. Megapixels and the dual flash are listed, plus autofocus and video. And software effects. But no mention of optics or sensor tech (or even aperture or ISO). It probably takes some serious sleuthing to even find out what they are. These things _just aren't the priority_. I wish it were otherwise.

Comment: Contrast [Apple's page on the iPhone 4S camera](http://www.apple.com/iphone/built-in-apps/camera.html). It's far from being all we could hope for as photographers, but it talks about the lens design (5 elements, f/2.4), IR filter, BSI sensor — and they even emphasize that you can _turn off_ the LED flash rather than trying to pretend that it's awesome. I'm not by any stretch an Apple fanboy, but I wish the Android makers would take some cues here.

Comment: This one seems to be a good enough camera: http://crave.cnet.co.uk/mobiles/altek-leo-14-megapixel-3x-optical-zoom-android-monster-phone-invades-europe-50001008/

Comment: @Luciano — that does look promising. Even if that particular one isn't great (and who knows; it might be), at least they're focusing on the camera. Still a little bit over-excited about megapixels and flash (and now zoom), but yeah, good to see.

Comment: @mattdm - I understand now. Sorry.

Comment: @Rory — no need to apologize! If anything, Google and company should be apologizing to _us_. :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out some reviews on Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 (e.g. [TechRadar](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/phones/mobile-phones/sony-ericsson-xperia-x10-679702/review?artc_pg=7), [Androinica](http://androinica.com/2010/04/sony-ericsson-xperia-x10-reviews-camera-camcorder/), [Amateur Photographer](http://www.amateurphotographer.co.uk/reviews/Sony_Ericsson_Xperia_X10_camera_phone_review_reviews_299655.html?offset=&offset=1)), which offers 4.7mm (35e: 35mm) f/2.8 camera with image stabilization. In [comparison to iPhone 4](http://phonecomparison.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/xperia-x10-versus-iphone-4-camera-performance-part-1-photos/), the X10 seems to do better in exposure metering and color reproduction, but photos have less detail.

Xperia Arc (and its minor improvement, Arc S) is marketed as an improvement upon X10, sporting a backlit Exmor R sensor (crop factor 7) and 4mm (35e: 28mm) f/2.4 lens, but the reviews I've read (e.g. [ePHOTOzine](http://www.ephotozine.com/article/sony-ericsson-xperia-arc-camera-phone-review-16984), [All About Symbian](http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/features/item/12866_Camera_champions_head_to_head.php), [phoneArena](http://www.phonearena.com/reviews/Sony-Ericsson-Xperia-arc-S-Review_id2851/page/3)) give me impression that while it's slightly better in low light, it's more average in moderate to good light. [Compared against iPhone 4](http://www.soyacincau.com/2011/04/12/camera-wars-xperia-arc-vs-iphone-4/), detail reproduction seems to have improved, but colors are less vibrant.

Another Android phone touted for its camera is LG Optimus 2X ([Phandroid](http://phandroid.com/2011/02/08/lg-optimus-2x-review/), [TechRadar](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/phones/mobile-phones/lg-optimus-2x-929388/review?artc_pg=7)). Shows duller colors and some blur in [comparison to iPhone 4](http://www.phonearena.com/news/LG-Optimus-2X-vs-Apple-iPhone-4-ultimate-camera--video-comparison_id16297).

Annoying thing about those camera phones is that none of them has any protection for its lens.

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't have any of the phones, but have been thinking about getting one myself.</sub>

Comment: My case protects my lens, and it actually works great with the case still on. I use an Otterbox case.

Comment: Probably off topic, but I just want to point out that the iPhone 4s does improve on many of the points outlined in the comparison given for the X10.

Comment: The Xperia X10 reviews do seem fairly positive, but, again, Sony Ericsson's own marketing materials don't take the camera seriously. It's [buried in the list of features](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/products/mobilephones/overview/xperiax10?cc=gb&lc=en#view=features_specifications), and there it only gets touted for its megapixels and face recognition software. The camera doesn't even make the [overview page](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/products/mobilephones/overview/xperiax10?cc=gb&lc=en#view=overview).

Comment: At least for the Arc they [mention the low-light capabilities of the sensor](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/corporate/products/phoneportfolio/specification/xperiaarc), but megapixels still get the headline.

Comment: @mattdm actually, the X10 overview page starts with "Stunning images..." headline - no need to mention camera when user cares about end result. Summarizing a camera in terms of megapixels, HD video and face detection is fairly common in P&S world, which a phone might hope to compete. I have to admit, they were doing better when they really had devoted Cyber-shot phones.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Droid X, I might be a skilled photographer, compared the image I got with my Droid X vs. HTC incredible, samsung fascinates, iPhone 3GS, iphone 4.

Droid X has the best camera in my opinion. (Droid X 2 is probably good too)

- Dual LED flash
- mechanical shutter
- Simply good optic in the small lens on the phone

Also, it takes awesome HD video too (in 720p)

I found that it's:
- incredibly sharp for close up (macro) photos
- portraits 
- landscape (although because of small lens does not capture detail out too far)

Comment: Plus, Droid X is a kick ass phone with great performance.

Answer (score 0):

My wife just got an HTC Sensation. I've been very impressed with the camera. You can see [some examples here](http://blog.garritys.org/2011/08/more-from-block-island.html). The only thing that it doesn't have is a dedicated shutter button. I think that they have addressed that in the latest version, but I haven't played with that one yet.

Comment: Nice, happy to see they made improvement on camera. I have Desire HD and that is sometimes struggling with low light conditions

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet released but Panasonic (aka Lumix) is planning to release a phone/camera hybrid which has optical zoom and 12MP count. I am not sure if the lens is Leica (like some other Lumix cameras) but it looks promising.

I shall add the model number once I found where I read about it.